# Name.com DNS Managment

Tags: dns, email, google-workspace

Hey, I am not good with all this DNS stuff but i am looking to use Google Apps to provide my email... To do this i need to add MX records but when i go to Domain>DNS management it says: "This domain is not properly configured to use DNS management. DNS Management will only work if the domain is using our name servers (NS1.NAME.COM, NS2.NAME.COM, NS3.NAME.COM, and NS4.NAME.COM)."

But i have to use Ns1.myserver.com ns2.myserver.com to make the site point to my server...

How do i add these mx records?

Answer (score 2):

you have to add MX records on the same DNS server where your domain name is handled

In case you are using a hosted domain, Google is providing instructions for the most common ones here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=140034

Answer (score 0):

Who's servers are ns1.myserver.com and ns2.myserver.com? Are they name servers you're running or are they the name servers of your web host which is different from name.com?

Whoever's name servers you're using, you have to go through them to change your DNS records.